# Difference between String s=" " and String s=null

Tags: java

I wrote the program to reverse the string

```
String original = "hello";
String rev = "";
for (int i = original.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    rev += original.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println("Reversal:" + rev);
```

The output is : `Reversal:olleh`

But, when I rewrite `String rev=""` as `String rev =null`

I get the output as `Reversal:nullolleh`

What is the difference between `null` and `""` character?

Comment: I wont answer since there are decent answers already, but you should use StringBuilder for this. It is much more performant. Or you can just use a char array as you know the exact size.

Answer (score 3):

`""` is an empty String, i.e. an object of the `String` class having 0 characters. `null` represents a lack of a reference to an object.

When you append a `null` reference to a String, the `null` reference is converted to a `String` whose value is `"null"`. Therefore, if you intend to append two `String`s, you should make sure that none of them is `null` (assuming you don't want your output to contain the `"null"` String).

However, using a `StringBuilder` is the preferred way to concatenate `String`s (though the compiler may do this optimization anyway when encountering the `String` concatenation operator `+`) :

```
String original = "hello";
StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = original.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    rev.append (original.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println("Reversal:" + rev.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = null; // no refrences to it at all
String s1 = "";
s.trim()// NullPointerException
s1.trim()// will give ""
```

Basically we use `""` if any string is blank, so doing any operation on it, ie calling methods on it wont give NPE.
While null is a keyword, will give NPE, if performed any operation on it. No references to it at all.

Answer (score 2):

`null` means your variable points to no object at all. `""` is the representation of a `String` object containing zero characters.